# Sorting players by FIDE blitz/rapid ratings

Tags: fide, rating, blitz, websites

In the FIDE advanced search it seems to only allow search by *[standard](https://ratings.fide.com/top_lists.phtml)* rating. Is there a way, for example, to search the list of players with descending blitz rating or rapid rating? My final goal is to find out strong blitz players with somewhat low standard ratings.

Is this possible with the FIDE website or is there another website which can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The FIDE site only allows you to sort by what you see, so no rapid or blitz option. However you can download the [raw data](http://ratings.fide.com/download/players_list_xml.zip) from the [FIDE download site](https://ratings.fide.com/download.phtml). Then it is a straightforward programming task to extract the data and load into a relational database database (I use SQL Server). From there you can write your own SQL queries to get the results you want.

> My final goal is to find out strong blitz players with somewhat low standard ratings.

You do not say what you mean by "strong blitz players" but, assuming that means over 2000, here is a list of the top 20 players with blitz >= 2000 sorted by (blitz - standard)

```
**Full Name                FIDEID     Blitz Standard    Difference**   
Karimi, Ahmad               1662996     2056    1334    722   
Brecevic, Liam              14617510    2331    1672    659   
Buachidze, Nikolai          13631624    2265    1645    620   
Herrera, Figueroa Amado Ama 5137470     2108    1496    612   
Khantadze, Teimuraz         13612840    2136    1573    563   
Sharypov, Sergey            34423346    2016    1489    527   
Pjesivac, Milan             16501195    2027    1540    487   
Giordani, Daniel            2046261     2132    1646    486   
Nikitenkov, Vladimir        24120944    2150    1680    470   
Kala, Piotr                 21844321    2031    1562    469   
Perovic, Radivoje           962066      2004    1546    458   
Jallow, Jalamang            21100128    2026    1572    454   
Koteski Aleksandar          15004821    2053    1606    447   
Kembay, T                   13712942    2127    1682    445   
Malkhasyan, Andrey          30931762    2105    1661    444   
Rafael Ramirez Leon         3531147     2031    1592    439   
Skrobic, Dragan             1032178     2450    2012    438   
Sistoza, Jester             5231019     2142    1711    431   
Soria, Angel                114219      2012    1583    429   
Nawrocki, Karol             1189921     2041    1616    425
```

Comment: thanks for this. is there a file which has all 3 ratings in 1 file. or do i need to download seperate files and do joins in sql

Comment: @cmgchess The xml zip download I linked has all three ratings - http://ratings.fide.com/download/players_list_xml.zip

Answer (score 6):

You can visit https://2700chess.com/. It lets you sort the rating. But it seems the display is limited.

I took the April 2022 FIDE rating file and created a list sorted on blitz in descending order. I also added blitz_rating - std_rating to see which player has a higher blitz than standard rating. If it is positive, the player's blitz rating is higher than standard. See the BR-SR column, showing only the top 200 blitz players. The "i" under the Flag column is "inactive". SRtng is the standard rating.

```
     ID Number                              Name  Fed Sex Tit   SRtng   RRtng   BRtng  B-day Flag  BR-SR  Age
0      2016192                  Nakamura, Hikaru  USA   M  GM  2750.0  2837.0  2850.0   1987  NaN  100.0   34
1      1503014                   Carlsen, Magnus  NOR   M  GM  2864.0  2847.0  2832.0   1990  NaN  -32.0   31
2      5202213                        So, Wesley  USA   M  GM  2778.0  2769.0  2814.0   1993  NaN   36.0   28
3       623539           Vachier-Lagrave, Maxime  FRA   M  GM  2758.0  2743.0  2813.0   1990  NaN   55.0   31
4     24101605               Artemiev, Vladislav  RUS   M  GM  2700.0  2695.0  2811.0   1998  NaN  111.0   23
5      8603820                        Yu, Yangyi  CHN   M  GM  2710.0  2738.0  2808.0   1994  NaN   98.0   27
6     12573981                 Firouzja, Alireza  FRA   M  GM  2804.0  2670.0  2791.0   2003  NaN  -13.0   18
7     24126055                     Dubov, Daniil  RUS   M  GM  2711.0  2712.0  2791.0   1996  NaN   80.0   25
8      8603677                       Ding, Liren  CHN   M  GM  2799.0  2836.0  2788.0   1992  NaN  -11.0   29
9     13300474                    Aronian, Levon  USA   M  GM  2785.0  2705.0  2773.0   1982  NaN  -12.0   39
10    13401319            Mamedyarov, Shakhriyar  AZE   M  GM  2771.0  2722.0  2769.0   1985  NaN   -2.0   36
11    24116068                       Giri, Anish  NED   M  GM  2773.0  2730.0  2766.0   1994  NaN   -7.0   27
12     4126025               Grischuk, Alexander  RUS   M  GM  2742.0  2759.0  2762.0   1983  NaN   20.0   38
13     8601445                      Bu, Xiangzhi  CHN   M  GM  2708.0  2642.0  2760.0   1985  NaN   52.0   36
14     1170546               Duda, Jan-Krzysztof  POL   M  GM  2750.0  2806.0  2760.0   1998  NaN   10.0   23
15     5000017                Anand, Viswanathan  IND   M  GM  2751.0  2675.0  2758.0   1969  NaN    7.0   52
16    35009192                    Erigaisi Arjun  IND   M  GM  2675.0  2450.0  2745.0   2003  NaN   70.0   18
17     2020009                  Caruana, Fabiano  USA   M  GM  2781.0  2784.0  2744.0   1992  NaN  -37.0   29
18      400041                    Adams, Michael  ENG   M  GM  2698.0  2651.0  2742.0   1971  NaN   44.0   50
19     4168119               Nepomniachtchi, Ian  RUS   M  GM  2773.0  2821.0  2740.0   1990  NaN  -33.0   31
20      703303                       Leko, Peter  HUN   M  GM  2663.0  2710.0  2738.0   1979    i   75.0   42
21      700070                     Polgar, Judit  HUN   F  GM  2675.0  2646.0  2736.0   1976   wi   61.0   45
22     4158814                 Andreikin, Dmitry  FID   M  GM  2729.0  2675.0  2736.0   1990  NaN    7.0   31
23    13306553              Martirosyan, Haik M.  ARM   M  GM  2633.0  2478.0  2735.0   2000  NaN  102.0   21
24     4167392                  Chadaev, Nikolai  RUS   M  GM  2591.0  2629.0  2733.0   1988    i  142.0   33
25     3503240          Dominguez Perez, Leinier  USA   M  GM  2756.0  2735.0  2728.0   1983  NaN  -28.0   38
26      603767                  Bauer, Christian  FRA   M  GM  2597.0  2604.0  2727.0   1977  NaN  130.0   44
27     2047640                    Xiong, Jeffery  USA   M  GM  2685.0  2729.0  2727.0   2000  NaN   42.0   21
28    24130737                Fedoseev, Vladimir  FID   M  GM  2701.0  2739.0  2726.0   1995  NaN   25.0   26
29     4102142                    Svidler, Peter  RUS   M  GM  2683.0  2752.0  2725.0   1976  NaN   42.0   45
30    14120828                 Bortnyk, Olexandr  UKR   M  GM  2604.0  2643.0  2723.0   1996  NaN  119.0   25
31     8602883                         Wang, Hao  CHN   M  GM  2744.0  2750.0  2712.0   1989  NaN  -32.0   32
32     4101588                 Kramnik, Vladimir  RUS   M  GM  2753.0  2756.0  2712.0   1975    i  -41.0   46
33    14100010                   Ivanchuk, Vasyl  UKR   M  GM  2678.0  2686.0  2710.0   1969    i   32.0   52
34     3503739            Bruzon Batista, Lazaro  USA   M  GM  2618.0  2619.0  2709.0   1982  NaN   91.0   39
35    14113007                 Kononenko, Dmitry  UKR   M  GM  2613.0  2546.0  2706.0   1988    i   93.0   33
36    25092340                       Nihal Sarin  IND   M  GM  2648.0  2604.0  2705.0   2004  NaN   57.0   17
37    13400924                 Radjabov, Teimour  AZE   M  GM  2753.0  2747.0  2705.0   1987  NaN  -48.0   34
38    10601457                      Amin, Bassem  EGY   M  GM  2685.0  2538.0  2699.0   1988  NaN   14.0   33
39     2040506                    Sevian, Samuel  USA   M  GM  2693.0  2586.0  2698.0   2000  NaN    5.0   21
40     4147235               Tomashevsky, Evgeny  RUS   M  GM  2708.0  2631.0  2695.0   1987  NaN  -13.0   34
41     6500617                Ramirez, Alejandro  USA   M  GM  2561.0  2579.0  2694.0   1988  NaN  133.0   33
42    14113147                  Kravtsiv, Martyn  UKR   M  GM  2598.0  2675.0  2694.0   1990  NaN   96.0   31
43    14118084                    Nyzhnyk, Illya  UKR   M  GM  2685.0  2658.0  2694.0   1996  NaN    9.0   25
44     8604436                        Li, Chao b  CHN   M  GM  2679.0  2645.0  2693.0   1989  NaN   14.0   32
45     3805662  Martinez Alcantara, Jose Eduardo  PER   M  GM  2598.0  2645.0  2690.0   1999  NaN   92.0   22
46     8603405                           Wei, Yi  CHN   M  GM  2729.0  2752.0  2686.0   1999  NaN  -43.0   22
47    12401137                    Le, Quang Liem  VIE   M  GM  2709.0  2660.0  2686.0   1991    i  -23.0   30
48      309095                     Navara, David  CZE   M  GM  2693.0  2701.0  2686.0   1985  NaN   -7.0   36
49    14109409                  Zubov, Alexander  UKR   M  GM  2598.0  2688.0  2685.0   1983  NaN   87.0   38
50     2023970                       Robson, Ray  USA   M  GM  2681.0  2605.0  2683.0   1994  NaN    2.0   27
51     4135539                Alekseenko, Kirill  FID   M  GM  2698.0  2639.0  2682.0   1997  NaN  -16.0   24
52    14200244              Kasimdzhanov, Rustam  UZB   M  GM  2656.0  2698.0  2681.0   1979  NaN   25.0   42
53     2209390                    Shirov, Alexei  ESP   M  GM  2693.0  2628.0  2678.0   1972  NaN  -15.0   49
54     4100140                    Bareev, Evgeny  CAN   M  GM  2631.0  2659.0  2678.0   1966  NaN   47.0   55
55      608742                Fressinet, Laurent  FRA   M  GM  2630.0  2676.0  2677.0   1981  NaN   47.0   40
56     1007998                      L'Ami, Erwin  NED   M  GM  2622.0  2647.0  2676.0   1985  NaN   54.0   36
57      718572                    Berkes, Ferenc  HUN   M  GM  2660.0  2637.0  2676.0   1985  NaN   16.0   36
58     4152956                  Vitiugov, Nikita  FID   M  GM  2724.0  2580.0  2673.0   1987  NaN  -51.0   34
59      605506                   Bacrot, Etienne  FRA   M  GM  2638.0  2720.0  2673.0   1983  NaN   35.0   38
60      117927             Perez Ponsa, Federico  ARG   M  GM  2553.0  2604.0  2672.0   1993  NaN  119.0   28
61     4168003                   Matlakov, Maxim  RUS   M  GM  2674.0  2671.0  2669.0   1991  NaN   -5.0   30
62     4119150                  Kobalia, Mikhail  RUS   M  GM  2596.0  2507.0  2667.0   1978  NaN   71.0   43
63     2900084                  Topalov, Veselin  BUL   M  GM  2730.0  2627.0  2667.0   1975  NaN  -63.0   46
64     4201345              Papaioannou, Ioannis  GRE   M  GM  2634.0  2614.0  2666.0   1976  NaN   32.0   45
65     8601429                         Wang, Yue  CHN   M  GM  2669.0  2710.0  2666.0   1987    i   -3.0   34
66    24133795                    Sarana, Alexey  FID   M  GM  2675.0  2654.0  2666.0   2000  NaN   -9.0   21
67    13401653                     Mamedov, Rauf  AZE   M  GM  2656.0  2584.0  2666.0   1988  NaN   10.0   33
68    24125890                  Oparin, Grigoriy  FID   M  GM  2674.0  2650.0  2665.0   1997  NaN   -9.0   24
69     1008013                  Tiviakov, Sergei  NED   M  GM  2567.0  2602.0  2665.0   1973  NaN   98.0   48
70    14204118            Abdusattorov, Nodirbek  UZB   M  GM  2661.0  2670.0  2663.0   2004  NaN    2.0   17
71    13502956                  Zhigalko, Sergei  BLR   M  GM  2572.0  2660.0  2662.0   1989    i   90.0   32
72    13301527                 Gharamian, Tigran  FRA   M  GM  2602.0  2650.0  2660.0   1984    i   58.0   37
73    14107180                 Drozdovskij, Yuri  UKR   M  GM  2616.0     NaN  2660.0   1984    i   44.0   37
74    14603853                       Lenic, Luka  SLO   M  GM  2634.0  2666.0  2659.0   1988  NaN   25.0   33
75     1017063                     Bok, Benjamin  NED   M  GM  2624.0  2608.0  2658.0   1995  NaN   34.0   26
76    14403803                     Kadric, Denis  BIH   M  GM  2576.0  2504.0  2657.0   1995  NaN   81.0   26
77      409561                 Jones, Gawain C B  ENG   M  GM  2666.0  2630.0  2657.0   1987  NaN   -9.0   34
78     9301348                 Salem, A.R. Saleh  UAE   M  GM  2690.0  2621.0  2657.0   1993  NaN  -33.0   28
79     4151348                 Khairullin, Ildar  RUS   M  GM  2615.0  2671.0  2657.0   1990  NaN   42.0   31
80     4120787                Malakhov, Vladimir  RUS   M  GM  2652.0  2670.0  2654.0   1980  NaN    2.0   41
81     5029465           Vidit, Santosh Gujrathi  IND   M  GM  2723.0  2617.0  2654.0   1994  NaN  -69.0   27
82      718939                     Balogh, Csaba  HUN   M  GM  2584.0  2618.0  2654.0   1987  NaN   70.0   34
83     2021285              Lenderman, Aleksandr  USA   M  GM  2591.0  2646.0  2651.0   1989  NaN   60.0   32
84    10601619                       Adly, Ahmed  EGY   M  GM  2596.0  2546.0  2650.0   1987  NaN   54.0   34
85    14105730                    Korobov, Anton  UKR   M  GM  2695.0  2677.0  2650.0   1985  NaN  -45.0   36
86    14101025               Onischuk, Alexander  USA   M  GM  2640.0  2693.0  2650.0   1975  NaN   10.0   46
87     1226380               Deac, Bogdan-Daniel  ROU   M  GM  2679.0  2553.0  2648.0   2001  NaN  -31.0   20
88     5018471                       Adhiban, B.  IND   M  GM  2633.0  2548.0  2648.0   1992  NaN   15.0   29
89     3208923                    Smirnov, Anton  AUS   M  GM  2600.0  2367.0  2647.0   2001  NaN   47.0   20
90      400173                 Sadler, Matthew D  ENG   M  GM  2694.0  2673.0  2646.0   1974    i  -48.0   47
91    13302000                 Andriasian, Zaven  ARM   M  GM  2584.0  2624.0  2646.0   1989  NaN   62.0   32
92     1107038                    Socko, Bartosz  POL   M  GM  2636.0  2571.0  2646.0   1978  NaN   10.0   43
93     3901211       Iturrizaga Bonelli, Eduardo  ESP   M  GM  2594.0  2638.0  2646.0   1989  NaN   52.0   32
94     8603332                      Lu, Shanglei  CHN   M  GM  2616.0  2613.0  2646.0   1995  NaN   30.0   26
95      738590                  Rapport, Richard  HUN   M  GM  2776.0  2785.0  2646.0   1996  NaN -130.0   25
96     4657101                     Svane, Rasmus  GER   M  GM  2648.0  2651.0  2645.0   1997  NaN   -3.0   24
97     2000024                      Kamsky, Gata  USA   M  GM  2661.0  2717.0  2645.0   1974  NaN  -16.0   47
98    13400819                   Mamedov, Nidjat  AZE   M  GM  2589.0  2624.0  2645.0   1985  NaN   56.0   36
99     4100018                   Kasparov, Garry  RUS   M  GM  2812.0  2783.0  2644.0   1963    i -168.0   58
100    2205530           Vallejo Pons, Francisco  ESP   M  GM  2704.0  2682.0  2644.0   1982  NaN  -60.0   39
101    7101384                Megaranto, Susanto  INA   M  GM  2529.0  2530.0  2644.0   1987  NaN  115.0   34
102    4203380                 Miladinovic, Igor  SRB   M  GM  2509.0  2582.0  2643.0   1974  NaN  134.0   47
103   14505320                  Jovanovic, Zoran  CRO   M  GM  2524.0  2564.0  2643.0   1979  NaN  119.0   42
104   14114038              Onyshchuk, Volodymyr  UKR   M  GM  2612.0  2661.0  2642.0   1991  NaN   30.0   30
105     813613                  Brunello, Sabino  ITA   M  GM  2502.0  2722.0  2641.0   1989  NaN  139.0   32
106   13300032                 Akopian, Vladimir  USA   M  GM  2622.0  2668.0  2641.0   1971  NaN   19.0   50
107    4162722                 Inarkiev, Ernesto  RUS   M  GM  2659.0  2678.0  2639.0   1985  NaN  -20.0   36
108     916366               Stojanovic, Mihajlo  SRB   M  GM  2502.0  2571.0  2638.0   1977  NaN  136.0   44
109    1202758           Nisipeanu, Liviu-Dieter  GER   M  GM  2640.0  2636.0  2637.0   1976  NaN   -3.0   45
110    4198603               Shimanov, Aleksandr  RUS   M  GM  2581.0  2616.0  2636.0   1992  NaN   55.0   29
111    4116992             Morozevich, Alexander  RUS   M  GM  2659.0  2651.0  2636.0   1977    i  -23.0   44
112   13405764                     Asadli, Vugar  AZE   M  GM  2579.0  2396.0  2635.0   2001  NaN   56.0   20
113   13300580                 Akobian, Varuzhan  USA   M  GM  2600.0  2639.0  2634.0   1983  NaN   34.0   38
114   13402129                    Safarli, Eltaj  AZE   M  GM  2589.0  2650.0  2634.0   1992  NaN   45.0   29
115     921637                    Markus, Robert  SRB   M  GM  2608.0  2625.0  2632.0   1983  NaN   24.0   38
116    4104226                Sakaev, Konstantin  RUS   M  GM  2603.0  2510.0  2632.0   1974  NaN   29.0   47
117     930849                 Predojevic, Borki  BIH   M  GM  2585.0  2587.0  2632.0   1987  NaN   47.0   34
118    2093596                Niemann, Hans Moke  USA   M  GM  2637.0  2529.0  2632.0   2003  NaN   -5.0   18
119   14205483                Sindarov, Javokhir  UZB   M  GM  2609.0  2425.0  2630.0   2005  NaN   21.0   16
120   12539929               Maghsoodloo, Parham  IRI   M  GM  2699.0  2631.0  2630.0   2000  NaN  -69.0   21
121   12500739              Ghaem Maghami, Ehsan  IRI   M  GM  2519.0  2550.0  2627.0   1982  NaN  108.0   39
122    1126881                  Swiercz, Dariusz  USA   M  GM  2664.0  2649.0  2627.0   1994  NaN  -37.0   27
123    4100026                   Karpov, Anatoly  RUS   M  GM  2617.0  2583.0  2627.0   1951    i   10.0   70
124    2809052                     Nabaty, Tamir  ISR   M  GM  2638.0  2646.0  2627.0   1991  NaN  -11.0   30
125   13600702                 Gelashvili, Tamaz  GEO   M  GM  2549.0     NaN  2627.0   1978    i   78.0   43
126    3503631           Delgado Ramirez, Neuris  PAR   M  GM  2613.0  2658.0  2627.0   1981  NaN   14.0   40
127   14109530            Areshchenko, Alexander  UKR   M  GM  2670.0  2588.0  2627.0   1986  NaN  -43.0   35
128    2226332         Ibarra Jerez, Jose Carlos  ESP   M  GM  2570.0  2570.0  2626.0   1985  NaN   56.0   36
129   13301616              Petrosian, Tigran L.  ARM   M  GM  2553.0  2623.0  2626.0   1984  NaN   73.0   37
130   13601733                     Izoria, Zviad  USA   M  GM  2602.0  2579.0  2626.0   1984    i   24.0   37
131     726265                  Prohaszka, Peter  HUN   M  GM  2570.0  2514.0  2626.0   1992  NaN   56.0   29
132    2803895                     Avrukh, Boris  ISR   M  GM  2567.0  2552.0  2625.0   1978    i   58.0   43
133    4122356                 Jakovenko, Dmitry  RUS   M  GM  2682.0  2684.0  2625.0   1983  NaN  -57.0   38
134    4100107                    Dreev, Aleksey  RUS   M  GM  2623.0  2596.0  2625.0   1969  NaN    2.0   52
135   13301004               Grigoryan, Karen H.  ARM   M  GM  2630.0  2660.0  2625.0   1995  NaN   -5.0   26
136    3800024            Granda Zuniga, Julio E  PER   M  GM  2630.0  2609.0  2624.0   1967    i   -6.0   54
137   14129574                Shevchenko, Kirill  UKR   M  GM  2652.0  2573.0  2624.0   2002  NaN  -28.0   19
138    4157770                Afromeev, Vladimir  RUS   M  FM  2633.0     NaN  2623.0   1954    i  -10.0   67
139     662399                   Lagarde, Maxime  FRA   M  GM  2626.0  2672.0  2622.0   1994  NaN   -4.0   27
140    3504409           Quesada Perez, Yuniesky  USA   M  GM  2589.0  2622.0  2622.0   1984  NaN   33.0   37
141    2905540                  Cheparinov, Ivan  BUL   M  GM  2672.0  2652.0  2622.0   1986  NaN  -50.0   35
142    4659600                     Khenkin, Igor  GER   M  GM  2506.0  2518.0  2621.0   1968  NaN  115.0   53
143    4180887                    Bocharov, Ivan  RUS   M  GM  2571.0  2570.0  2620.0   1990  NaN   49.0   31
144    4651340                   Buhmann, Rainer  GER   M  GM  2564.0  2616.0  2620.0   1981  NaN   56.0   40
145     400025                    Short, Nigel D  ENG   M  GM  2620.0  2537.0  2619.0   1965  NaN   -1.0   56
146    2805677                    Gelfand, Boris  ISR   M  GM  2670.0  2635.0  2619.0   1968  NaN  -51.0   53
147    2004887                    Shankland, Sam  USA   M  GM  2709.0  2625.0  2618.0   1991  NaN  -91.0   30
148   13601520                    Jobava, Baadur  GEO   M  GM  2588.0  2664.0  2617.0   1983  NaN   29.0   38
149    2293307              Santos Latasa, Jaime  ESP   M  GM  2656.0  2593.0  2617.0   1996  NaN  -39.0   25
150   24175439                  Esipenko, Andrey  FID   M  GM  2723.0  2679.0  2617.0   2002  NaN -106.0   19
151    1710400                  Grandelius, Nils  SWE   M  GM  2656.0  2652.0  2617.0   1993  NaN  -39.0   28
152   35093487                  Sadhwani, Raunak  IND   M  GM  2628.0  2533.0  2616.0   2005  NaN  -12.0   16
153     911925                Indjic, Aleksandar  SRB   M  GM  2613.0  2516.0  2616.0   1995  NaN    3.0   26
154    4108566               Tsydypov, Zhamsaran  RUS   M  GM  2533.0  2574.0  2614.0   1996  NaN   81.0   25
155   24107581                  Predke, Alexandr  FID   M  GM  2688.0  2601.0  2614.0   1994  NaN  -74.0   27
156    4212312                Pavlidis, Antonios  GRE   M  GM  2546.0  2614.0  2613.0   1993  NaN   67.0   28
157    1122401                 Moranda, Wojciech  POL   M  GM  2630.0  2575.0  2613.0   1988  NaN  -17.0   33
158    5016690                  Negi, Parimarjan  IND   M  GM  2639.0  2613.0  2613.0   1993    i  -26.0   28
159    4117301              Cherniaev, Alexander  FID   M  GM  2397.0  2323.0  2612.0   1969  NaN  215.0   52
160    3404650     Castellanos Rodriguez, Renier  ESP   M  IM  2476.0  2488.0  2612.0   1982  NaN  136.0   39
161   13409301                 Muradli, Mahammad  AZE   M  IM  2537.0  2396.0  2611.0   2003  NaN   74.0   18
162   14109603                  Karjakin, Sergey  RUS   M  GM  2747.0  2736.0  2611.0   1990  NaN -136.0   31
163   14204223              Vokhidov, Shamsiddin  UZB   M  GM  2536.0  2504.0  2611.0   2002  NaN   75.0   19
164    4150120                       Lysyj, Igor  RUS   M  GM  2603.0  2556.0  2611.0   1987  NaN    8.0   34
165    1118358               Wojtaszek, Radoslaw  POL   M  GM  2696.0  2647.0  2610.0   1987  NaN  -86.0   34
166   14102196                  Baklan, Vladimir  UKR   M  GM  2591.0  2640.0  2610.0   1978  NaN   19.0   43
167     950122                     Ivic, Velimir  SRB   M  GM  2625.0  2437.0  2610.0   2002  NaN  -15.0   19
168     200930                 Gurevich, Mikhail  BEL   M  GM  2575.0  2562.0  2610.0   1959  NaN   35.0   62
169   12510130                      Idani, Pouya  IRI   M  GM  2638.0  2509.0  2610.0   1995  NaN  -28.0   26
170    1039784               Van Foreest, Jorden  NED   M  GM  2714.0  2645.0  2609.0   1999  NaN -105.0   22
171     616915                  Gozzoli, Yannick  FRA   M  GM  2595.0  2621.0  2609.0   1983  NaN   14.0   38
172    2101246                    Leitao, Rafael  BRA   M  GM  2592.0  2628.0  2609.0   1979    i   17.0   42
173    2026961                Naroditsky, Daniel  USA   M  GM  2616.0  2639.0  2608.0   1995  NaN   -8.0   26
174    1105663                 Kempinski, Robert  POL   M  GM  2559.0  2498.0  2608.0   1977  NaN   49.0   44
175   13601326            Azmaiparashvili, Zurab  GEO   M  GM  2637.0  2619.0  2608.0   1960    i  -29.0   61
176   14907526                   Michalik, Peter  CZE   M  GM  2581.0  2526.0  2607.0   1990  NaN   26.0   31
177    1503707                Hammer, Jon Ludvig  NOR   M  GM  2621.0  2647.0  2607.0   1990  NaN  -14.0   31
178    3801497                   Cordova, Emilio  PER   M  GM  2544.0  2610.0  2607.0   1991  NaN   63.0   30
179    4119142                 Korotylev, Alexey  RUS   M  GM  2573.0     NaN  2606.0   1977    i   33.0   44
180   14120844                Danilenko, Dmitriy  UKR   M  FM  2401.0  2434.0  2606.0   1994    i  205.0   27
181   24604747               Huschenbeth, Niclas  GER   M  GM  2611.0  2572.0  2605.0   1992  NaN   -6.0   29
182    2257327               Salgado Lopez, Ivan  ESP   M  GM  2612.0  2550.0  2605.0   1991  NaN   -7.0   30
183   14103320                Ponomariov, Ruslan  UKR   M  GM  2636.0  2673.0  2605.0   1983  NaN  -31.0   38
184   13302485                  Melkumyan, Hrant  ARM   M  GM  2649.0  2686.0  2604.0   1989  NaN  -45.0   32
185    6300545                      Sanal, Vahap  TUR   M  GM  2593.0  2539.0  2603.0   1998  NaN   10.0   23
186     722413                     Banusz, Tamas  HUN   M  GM  2608.0  2554.0  2602.0   1989  NaN   -6.0   32
187    8603154                           Ma, Qun  CHN   M  GM  2645.0  2570.0  2602.0   1991  NaN  -43.0   30
188    1111914                      Miton, Kamil  POL   M  GM  2568.0  2544.0  2602.0   1984  NaN   34.0   37
189   14506688                       Brkic, Ante  CRO   M  GM  2611.0  2597.0  2602.0   1988  NaN   -9.0   33
190    4189302                   Sjugirov, Sanan  RUS   M  GM  2696.0  2578.0  2602.0   1993  NaN  -94.0   28
191    2000075                      Dlugy, Maxim  USA   M  GM  2513.0  2577.0  2602.0   1966    i   89.0   55
192    8602980                        Hou, Yifan  CHN   F  GM  2650.0  2621.0  2601.0   1994    w  -49.0   27
193    4113403                 Zvjaginsev, Vadim  RUS   M  GM  2599.0  2488.0  2601.0   1976  NaN    2.0   45
194   14102951                    Eljanov, Pavel  UKR   M  GM  2681.0  2653.0  2601.0   1983  NaN  -80.0   38
195    4202031                  Banikas, Hristos  GRE   M  GM  2588.0  2615.0  2601.0   1978  NaN   13.0   43
196   13306766                   Sargsyan, Shant  ARM   M  GM  2639.0  2477.0  2600.0   2002  NaN  -39.0   19
197    4159659                     Yudin, Sergei  RUS   M  GM  2469.0  2460.0  2600.0   1986  NaN  131.0   35
198   14502879                     Kozul, Zdenko  CRO   M  GM  2617.0  2526.0  2600.0   1966  NaN  -17.0   55
199   25059530                  Praggnanandhaa R  IND   M  GM  2624.0  1927.0  2599.0   2005  NaN  -25.0   16
```

#### Code ([Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29)/[Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29))

```
import pandas as pd

fn = r'F:\Downloads\players_list\players_list_foa.txt'
df = pd.read_fwf(fn)

dfbr = df[(df['BRtng'] >= 2500)]
dfbr = dfbr.sort_values(by='BRtng', ascending=False)
dfbr = dfbr.reset_index(drop=True)

dfbr = dfbr.drop(['WTit', 'OTit', 'FOA', 'SGm', 'SK', 'RGm', 'Rk', 'BGm', 'BK'], axis=1)
dfbr['BR-SR'] = dfbr['BRtng'] - dfbr['SRtng']
dfbr['Age'] = 2021 - dfbr['B-day']
print(dfbr.head(200).to_string())
```

#### File source

Download the highlighted file (txt format) from http://ratings.fide.com/download.phtml

[image]

Comment: this looks cool. is this sql?

Comment: I am using pandas. Read the FIDE rating text file into pandas dataframe, filter out unnecessary columns and add calculated columns BR-SR and Age.

Answer (score 2):

1. Access https://ratings.fide.com/
2. Click on Advanced Search
3. Select the desired rating in the "Select Rating" dropbox (top left)
4. In "Sort by", check "Rating (FIDE rated only)", and optionally check "Ascending" or "Descending" below that.
5. Even outside of your specific scenario, you'll probably want to restrict the results in some way, either by restricting the rating range or age range or by selecting a country, etc.
6. Click on "Search".

This isn't such a new feature, so I'm a bit confused by the previous answers.

Comment: this is only for standard ratings am i right? i wanted for blitz and maybe also rapid

Comment: apparently they have added blitz and rapid as well. when i posted the question it wasn't there